# Is this an adequate design for a +3.3V / +9V / -9V power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I'm building a small audio processing unit for my own needs and because of all the ICs used I need to use bipolar supplies + 3.3V for the digital parts. I'm going to build this over a pref-board, this might not be the best solution but I'm not going to spin a PCB for a single unit.

I think the general design is pretty clear from the schematic however some pointers:
* Diode is for reverse polarity protection. This circuit is powered from a 9VDC power brick which is already regulated. The diode might burn if the reverse polarity is for a long time but I am OK with that.
* The LCL filters are for removing high freq. from the analog supplies.
* I did not include a diode from the 3.3V to the Vin port (anode to 3.3V cathode to Vin) however it might be a good idea so that the caps form the circuit won't discharge into the regulator.

The grounds are shorted at a single point to prevent current from the digital part going through the analog part. Pointers and suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you put a fuse in series with Vin the fuse would blow protecting your circuit including the diode from damage when polarity is reversed. But if you use a standard jack for the power connection there's not so much chance of revese polarity anyway. I think you miss a connection between VIN and +9VDC. In your cicruit +9VDC wil be 0V always.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Yes, I'm missing a small link at the input. Thanks!

Comment: Current consumption of devices not shown is important to be able to say whether this is a good circuit. Voltage ripple expected on -9V output is also something to be expected so look into whether it might be too high (under load).

Comment: Just a style comment for future reference. If the components have unique reference designators, it makes it much easier to discuss the circuit.